# SyncedQuote field is read only within a trigger

Tags: apex, fields, before-trigger, clone, read-only

I'm trying to clone an Opportunity at before update event of Opportunity. But it throws me error,

> Opportunity SyncedQuote field is read only within a trigger

```
    for(Opportunity oppoFull :listOpp){
        if (!setOppId.contains(oppoFull.Id))
            continue;
        if (oppoFull.clone__c){
           Opportunity oppoCopy = oppoFull.clone(false,true);

           listClonedOpps.add(oppoCopy);
        }
    }

    insert listClonedOpps;
```

I assumed it's because Opportunity's Synced Quote,

and tried setting `oppoCopy.SyncedQuoteId = null;`

Not resolved, not sure [why this field is READ-ONLY only in trigger](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=quotes_sync_troubleshooting.htm&type=5), Saw people have done similar triggers with @future methods. Any help on workarounds to resolve it? without an asynchronous method?

Really appreciate any tips, thoughts on this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it resolved with following workaround.

**Created below 2 methods,**

```
private static String populateOppSelectAllFields(Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fldObjMap) {
        List<Schema.SObjectField> fldObjMapValues = fldObjMap.values();
        String theQuery = 'SELECT ';
        for(Schema.SObjectField s : fldObjMapValues) {
            if (s.getDescribe().getName()=='SyncedQuoteId')
                continue;

            if (s.getDescribe().isCreateable()) {
                String theName = s.getDescribe().getName();
                theQuery += theName + ',';
            }
        }
        return theQuery.subString(0, theQuery.length() - 1);
    }

    private static Opportunity cloneOpp(Opportunity opp){
        Opportunity newOpp = new Opportunity();

        Map<String,Object> fieldsMap = opp.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();

        for(String fld :fieldsMap.keyset()){
            newOpp.put(fld, fieldsMap.get(fld));
        }

        newOpp.Id = null;
        return newOpp;
    }
```

**In Trigger handler code,**

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fldObjMap = schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.fields.getMap();

        String query = populateOppSelectAllFields(fldObjMap) + ' FROM Opportunity WHERE Id  IN :setOppId ';
        List<Opportunity> listOpp2Clone = Database.query(query);
        Map<Id, Opportunity> mapOpp2Clone = new Map<Id, Opportunity>(listOpp2Clone);

for(Opportunity opp :listOpp){
   Opportunity oppoCopy =  cloneOpp(mapOpp2Clone.get(opp.Id));
   listClonedOpps.add(oppoCopy);
 }

insert listClonedOpps;
```